# OpenWrt bricked router is not connected via USB to serial cable

Tags: ssh, putty, openwrt, router, telnet

I have a problem in my OpenWRT router when I try to upgrade my router

([TP-Link TL-WDR-3600](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WDR3600.html)) to openwrt firmware via web ui. Now my router is bricked and I can't  connect

the router via WebUI (192.168.1.1), [putty](http://www.putty.org/) and [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php). I checked the `ipconfig` command in

**command prompt**. But the Default gateway is missing.

[image]

Finally I try to connect via USB to serial cable using putty.

[image]
[image]

But the putty is shown a blank screen for a long time. ( 30 minutes ).

I am really hopeless, I think my router is seriously crashed.

Could you please suggest any advice?

Comment: How have you hooked up the serial port to the router? Can you try a speed of 9,600bps - 115,200 may be too fast.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. But i tried this both values. but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not panic. I do not think that your router is bricked. It is just unreachable for you PC. Did you try to set the IP address of your PC manually to 192.168.1.2? Your PC now has 169.254.17.129. This address cannot communicate to your router.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I so sorry I made this commanad prompt screen shot in my laptop. But there is a wifi network connected in the laptop.

Comment: How did you try to connect to your router? WIFI or network cable? Should be by network cable and with an IP address that is in the same subnet as 192.168.1.1.

Comment: I am using Network cable. Now i disable the wireless lan.

Comment: What IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. I stop the research and contact the retail seller (it's in warrenty period.). Now i got a new router :)